# Setting ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT in travis.yml?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Travis runs substitutions on dollar signs, so a ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT like the following doesn't propagate properly into the system:

```
env:
  global:
    - ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT=[${severity}] ${time} ${file}:${line} ${node}: ${message}
```

It also needs to get put into Docker container/s that travis runs, in commands like

```
- docker exec ... -e ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT=${ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT} ... ${DOCKER_IMAGE_REPO}:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
```

I'll cross post this to an answers site that has travis questions if no one knows here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353072/setting-rosconsole_format-in-travis.yml?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2020-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Single quotes were it as commented above (triple single quotes also work, double quotes **do not** work, you'll see a lot of `[][:]:` or similar depending on the exact format string):

```
- ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='[${severity}] ${time} ${file}:${line} ${node}: ${message}'
```

I made an simple example to experiment with:

https://github.com/lucasw/ros_docker/blob/master/.travis.yml

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2020-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't want whatever is interpreting the YAML to interpret a string, you typically have to quote it. Use single quotes (ie: `'`). That could make this work.

Quoting `ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` is a good idea anyway.

Note: this is not a ROS problem, but more a generic "how do I do this with travis / in YAML?" question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1